# PHPExcel can not export file to download?

Tags: php, export, phpexcel

I use PHPExcel to export my MySQL data ta xls file, but when I run it echo somethings instead download file to my local. I use firefox on centos 7.

My error like this:

`��ࡱ�;��  ?����@ABCDEFGHIJKL������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������`

here is my code:

```
foreach($this->items as $r => $dataRow) {
            $row = $baseRow + $r;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore($row,1);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A'.$row, $r+1)
                ->setCellValue('B'.$row, $dataRow['a'])
                ->setCellValue('C'.$row, $dataRow['b_display'])
                ->setCellValue('D'.$row, $dataRow['c_count'])
                ->setCellValue('E'.$row, $dataRow['d'])
                ->setCellValue('F'.$row, $dataRow['e'])
                ->setCellValue('G'.$row, '=C'.$row.'*D'.$row);
        }
        $filename=mt_rand(1,100000).'.xls'; //just some random filename

        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=DoanhNghiep.xls");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');  //downloadable file is in Excel 2003 format (.xls)
        $objWriter->save('php://output');  //send it to user, of course you can save it to disk also!
        exit;
```

Anybody can help me ? tks for reading !

Comment: Your browser can't read `.xls` files, so it'll download them instead.

Comment: Make sure that your script is sending absolutely nothing to the browser except for the saved file..... it's likely that you're sending something before that; check for echo or print statements in your code, or anything that isn't between PHP Tags.... even a new line character will corrupt the output

Comment: PS `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` is the content type for an `xlsx` file, not for an `xls` file

Comment: I have no idea why it did not download :(

Comment: for .xls, please try : ` "application/vnd.ms-excel" ` as `Content-type`

Answer (score 1):

```
I assume that your code of foreach is correct you can try this modified header code

        $filename=mt_rand(1,100000).'.xls'; //just some random filename

        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$filename."'");
        header("Pragma: public");
        header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');  //downloadable file is in Excel 2003 format (.xls)
        $objWriter->save('php://output');  //send it to user, of course you can save it to disk also!
        exit;
```

Or You can also try Below code that is working for me in my project

```
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Booking Report.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;
```

Comment: thanks you, but it it still can not downloadable. It echo to html instead download :(